# Global Assembly Cache Folder in setup projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm new to creating installers using Visual Studio, and was wondering about the Global Assembly Cache folder. In the case where a other version of a dll (same version number) is already existing in Gac, will it override or ignore the old dll?

Is there any method to set this in the setup project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/08/10/8847259.aspx) seems to describe the same problem and possible workarounds.